# Can I always refuse to share my location when a website asks for it in Opera?

Tags: android-12, opera-browser, google-pixel-6

I don't want to always click on no in those windows:

[image]

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12.

Comment: @AndrewT. the setting for location access doesn't stick even after you select "Remember choice" is just for this website I believe. I'd like to remember the choice for all the websites

Comment: Have you tried going via the Android settings, and revoke location permission from the app itself? If you do not want *any* website having location access, that would probably be the easiest approach.